# MomentJS: Display formatted range between two arbitrary dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two arbitrary dates that I would like to compare using MomentJS. By "arbitrary," I mean that neither of them are now (i.e. `moment()`).

I would like to display both of these dates as a nicely-formatted string based on the difference between them. For example, if the difference between them is just a few hours, I'd rather display something like `"5 am to 8am"`, rather than `"1/1/2018 5:00am to 1/1/2018 8:00am"`.

Put more succinctly, I'm trying to see if moment can determine which fields are equivalent, and based on this, format the time range as a string without any redundant information.

Is there a way to do this using standard functions in MomentJS?

---

Here's what I understand so far:

The functions such as `toNow()`, `fromNow()`, `to()`, and `from()` all provide relative time ranges, but these are in reference to now. What I'm looking for is this same interface, but *without referencing now*.

I believe that my options are either to:

1. Use one of the aforementioned functions to compare the two dates, drop the suffix, and display something like `"1/1/2018 5:00am + 3 hours"`, OR
2. Use a [`duration`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/) to compare the dates, and add custom code to determine equivalent quantities, and set the format accordingly. E.g. if years, months, weeks, and days are equivalent, format each timestamp as `"h:mm:ss a"`.

The output of the second option would be much more desirable. Essentially, I'm trying to implement this option using MomentJS and as little custom code as possible.

Comment: Moment.js is a large library with lots of ways of doing things.  Here's my advice - subtract the later from the first moment, then format as needed (maybe use `.humanize()' https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/

Comment: It looks like there is a plugin called [Twix](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/twix/) for formatting ranges readably. It looks like this would solve my problem, but I need to avoid using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is handled externally by a plugin called [Twix](http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/docs.html#smart-formatting).